# Index out of range exception on array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to reverse an array. This is my code:

```
using System;

class Hello
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] num  = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int index = num.Length - 1;
        int[] newNum = new int[index];

        for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
        {
            newNum[i] = num[index];  // error     
            index--;        
            Console.WriteLine(newNum[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the console prints

```
5
4
3
2
```

and then returns an error:

> IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled

on the line:

```
newNum[i] = num[index];
```

What's wrong with that line of code? When I print `num[0]` before that for loop it works fine.

Comment: Well yes, your `newNum` array is one element smaller than your `num` array, but your loop is written as if it's the same length as `num`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Why not use Enumerable.Reverse? [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358497(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @croxy: Please don't remove relevant code. The `using` directive for the `System` namespace is necessary to make this code compile.

Comment: ugh silly mistake. Thanks

Comment: @JonSkeet Oops, I'm sorry my mistake. Will not happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

length of your new array is 4. that's mean I'll cover from 0 to 3

```
int[] newNum = new int[index];
```

and your loop will go i=4

when i will 4 your code will collapse. as newNum support only to 3rd index.

this should be

```
int[] newNum = new int[index+1];
```